# Excel cell contains reference to other cell. Set a range to point at the other cell

Tags: vba, excel

A1 Cell formula in Sheet1:

```
=Sheet2!B6
```

In VBA I am getting cell A1 formula, but I wish to do something like this:

```
Dim rng1 as range
Set rng1 = worksheets("Sheet1").formula
```

I know the above is not right, the range would require an object and not a formula.

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to get out of your formula? The formula that's in Sheet2!B6?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25286978/2127508) seems relevant as your formula refers to another sheet

Comment: @BruceWayne I am getting the cell reference (sheet2 B6) from the formula. Then I want to use it to set a range object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little unclear on whether you have the value `Sheet2!B6` in Sheet1!A1 or actually have the formula `=Sheet2!B6` in Sheet1!A1.

For the value in Sheet1!A1,

```
Dim rng1 as range
Set rng1 = range(worksheets("Sheet1").range("a1").value)
debug.print rng1.address(0, 0, external:=true)    '<~~ Sheet2!B6
```

For the formula in Sheet1!A1,

```
Dim rng1 as range
Set rng1 = range(mid(worksheets("Sheet1").range("a1").formula, 2))
debug.print rng1.address(0, 0, external:=true)    '<~~ Sheet2!B6
```

Comment: Great. thanks. For the First answer, just change ".value" to ".formula", which is simpler than the second answer (also right.)

Answer (score 1):

What if you did something like this:

```
Sub t()
Dim rng As Range, formulaSheet$, formulaCell$
Dim theFormula$

theFormula = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Formula
theFormula = Right(theFormula, Len(theFormula) - 1)
Debug.Print theFormula

formulaSheet = Left(theFormula, WorksheetFunction.Search("!", theFormula) - 1)
formulaCell = Right(theFormula, Len(theFormula) - WorksheetFunction.Search("!", theFormula))
Debug.Print formulaSheet & ", " & formulaCell

Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Sheets(formulaSheet).Range(formulaCell)
myRange.Select
End Sub
```